# How to typehint generators in php?

Tags: php, phpstorm, generator, type-hinting, phpdoc

Assume you have a class like:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function __construct(public int $id, public string $foo)
    {
    }
}
```

and a generator creating multiple instances of that class like this:

```
$myGenerator = function (): \Generator {
     yield new MyClass(id: 21, foo: 'fnord');
     yield new MyClass(id: 13, foo: 'baz');
     yield new MyClass(id: 42, foo: 'Thanks for the fish');
};
```

How can I typehint a generator function so that it infers the type of each element during iteration?

```php
foreach ($myGenerator as $instance) {
    $instance-> // no autocompletion in IDE as type is not known
}
```

I don't want to do:

```php
foreach ($myGenerator as $instance) {
    /** @var MyClass $instance */
    $instance-> // now autocomplete works inside an IDE
}
```

as it would pester each usage of the generator with redundant typehints. I want to provide it once at best on the level of the return type of the generator.

Is there a better alternative to typehint a generator?

In pseudo-code, I would expect of being able to do something along the lines of:

```php
$myGenerator = function (): \Generator<MyClass> {...}
```

I assume php's type-system isn't up for this, I wouldn't mind using phpdocs / phpstan. Main use case is IDE support (in my case phpStorm though it should work beyond that).

Comment: Apparently, it may be possible via phpstan, though I don't know how to activate within phpstorm yet: https://phpstan.org/blog/generics-in-php-using-phpdocs

Comment: The support for generics in PhpStorm has been added in the latest version, which was released some days ago - so if you can use PHPDocs for this (which does not mean that you have to use PHPStan, as both PhpStorm and PHPStan solely read that data), that might help after updating PhpStorm

Comment: @NicoHaase With latest version, do you mean 2021.2 or do you mean EAP? As it appears non-functional on my machine with 2021.2. Could you please expand on this?

Comment: @NicoHaase I found this blog post, and though it talks about generics documentation, I don't know if that can be applied to generators and how so. https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2021/07/phpstorm-2021-2-beta/

Comment: Yeah, exactly like that? Or like `/** @var MyClass[] $generator **/`?

Answer (score 8):

Like other collections over phpdoc

```php
/**
* @return \Generator<MyClass>
* or
* @return \Generator|MyClass[]
*/
$myGenerator = function (): \Generator {
   yield new MyClass(id: 21, foo: 'fnord');
   yield new MyClass(id: 13, foo: 'baz');
   yield new MyClass(id: 42, foo: 'Thanks for the fish');
};
```