# How to typehint this Generator?

Tags: php, types, phpstan

My data provider is sending arrays. The first element is always a string, the second one an array of Token.

```php
public static function dataProvider(): Generator
{
    yield ['15', [new Token(15, Lexer::T_INTEGER, 0)];
    //And so on...
}
```

I would like to "typehint" this provider. As suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68638379/how-to-typehint-generators-in-php), I tried:

```php
    /** 
     * @return Generator<array{string, Token<int, int|string>[]}>
     */
```

But PhpStan is returning an error:

```
  Generator expects value type 
     array{string, array<Doctrine\Common\Lexer\Token<int, int|string>>}, 
     array{'15',   array{Doctrine\Common\Lexer\Token<int, int>}       } given.
```

```
      Offset 1 (array<Doctrine\Common\Lexer\Token<int, int|string>>)
        does not accept type array{Doctrine\Common\Lexer\Token<int, int>}:
        Template type V on class Doctrine\Common\Lexer\Token is not
        covariant. Learn more:
        https://phpstan.org/blog/whats-up-with-template-covariant
```

I read the [mentioned link](https://phpstan.org/blog/whats-up-with-template-covariant) and this one ["Type-safe iterators and generators"](https://phpstan.org/blog/generics-in-php-using-phpdocs#type-safe-iterators-and-generators), but I still don't understand how to type-safe this Generator correctly.

I know that the error disappear when I use `@return Generator<array{string, Token[]}>`, but I need to specify types in Token. FI, the errors are replaced by

> Method LongitudeOne\Geo\String\Tests\LexerTest::dataProvider() return type with generic class Doctrine\Common\Lexer\Token does not specify its types: T, V

If it could help, class Token is declared in `doctrine/lexer`:

```php
/**
 * @template T of UnitEnum|string|int
 * @template V of string|int
 * @implements ArrayAccess<string,mixed>
 */
final class Token implements ArrayAccess
```